# Performance measurement

Tags: divisibility

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885125/performance-increase-claculation) on the forum, and came to the conclusion that performance would be calculated using the following formula:

```
1 - lower/higher * 100
```

Based on that, between `0.246` and `0.321`, would the performance be increased by `23%`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the original value of a measurement is $0.246$ and the new value is $0.321$ you calculate the relative change by dividing:
$$
\frac{\text{new}}{\text{old}} = \frac{0.321}{0.246} = 1.30 .
$$
That corresponds to a $30\%$ increase, because you can rewrite the equation as
$$
{\text{new}} = 1.30 \times{\text{old}} = 1 \times {\text{old}} + 0.30 \times  {\text{old}} .
$$

The logic has nothing to do with whether the measurement went up or down. You don't always divide the smaller number by the larger. If the change was from $5$ to $4$ the calculation is
$$
\frac{\text{new}}{\text{old}} = \frac{4}{5} = 0.8 = 1 - 0.2
$$
which corresponds to a $20\%$ decrease.